# Download issues via HTTP for specific site

Tags: java, http, tcp

I am using a proprietary tool to download software from a software provider. In the backend it is a java application which uses plain http (or optionally https) to retrieve the software.

Recently however the downloads have been failing. Note that I do not have access to the source code of the download tool and that I am behind a proxy server. The tool connects multiple times to the same host before starting the actual download. These connections are usually successful though they appear somewhat slow (this is subjective of course).

The tool performs some logging and when it fails we get this exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
 at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:116)
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2676)
```

When listening in via wireshark I see some peculiar behavior (or at least peculiar to my untrained eye).
The download will proceed "normally" for a while until this happens:

- our server does not send an ACK for a specific packet
- the proxy server (after a timeout) performs a retransmission
- our server sends an ACK
- no more traffic occurs until after exactly 3 minutes (a timeout configured on the proxy server), the proxy sends a TCP RST and we get the above java error

Some additionaly information:

1) I also have access to an amazon server that is not on our network and it performs the download without a hitch. We have asked at least 2 other people on different networks to try the download and it works flawlessly.

2) We use the same server and proxy to connect to other http/https sites all the time without issue, this includes big downloads from time to time

Comment: are you able to download without using the downloading tool? e.g. using web browser with proxy setting.

Comment: This is very hard to test at first glance as the tool performs some sort of additional custom authentication before starting the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by tweaking some timeout settings on the proxy server though they have not given us much feedback as to what exactly has changed or why only this particular site was impacted.